# How to push specific items in a new array during a map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm mapping over an array of objects. I only want to display the items that can fit in a single line. The other ones have to be pushed in a new array, that will be displayed elsewhere (a "see more button" + a popover).

In order to do it, I have a ref on the div that encompasses the mapped items. Once its height changes, I know I'm on another line, and that it's time to stop displaying items.

I wrote:

```js
const Component = ({myArray}) => {
let ref = React.useRef();
const { height, width } = useSize(ref);
const availableSpace = 24;
const otherArray = [];

return (  
  <div ref={ref} style={{display: "flex" flexWrap:"flew-wrap"}}>
   {myArray.map({label} => {
        height > 24 && otherArray.push({label});
        return (
            //stuff
         )
      })}
    {otherArray && otherArray.length > 0 && (
    <button onClick={()=> showRemainingItemsInAPopover}>
        +{otherArray.length}
    </button>
    )}
    )
   }
```

Sadly, React renders all the items, and then pushes all of them again in otherArray.

How to properly separate my array in two in real time?

Thanks!

Comment: Not that I think it will absolutely matter, but would you mind posting the rest of the snippet? (//stuff)

Comment: I have updated my original post with a complete code (I have just removed the "how each item renders" part). //stuff is just not to bother you with css. It's just a layout with styled components to display each item.

Comment: But the //stuff is what's being returned by your map() function. I feel like that's pretty important to see.

Comment: There are 2 main issues: height is not updated in the scope of the map function, and also the map does not filter the results, you should use filter instead

Comment: If height isn't a property of the array elements then the result for any map or filter will always be the same since for each element the height never changes...

Comment: Yes, "height" is related to the main div's height. This information is obtained thanks to a ref. Its value is accurately updated. For more simplicity, I've used the hook useSize from "react-hook-size". Filtering won't help here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use filter function  :

```
 <div ref={ref}>
  {myArray.map({label} => {
    height > 24 && otherArray.push({label});
    return (
        //stuff
     )
  }).filter(() => height <= 24)}
```

but i'd like to see more code to you help more.

Comment: Yeah it's probably worth noting that if height is declared out of the scope of the filter/map functions then it will always be the same value (and hence either all elements will be > 24 or all values will be <= 24)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve the issue here. I have updated my original post with a complete code (I have just removed the "how each item renders" parts).

Comment: And if you try your condition in console.log height > 24, did you get one value < 24 ?

Comment: It just display true or false. The height is not an item's property. It is related to the main div's height. This information is obtained thanks a to a ref.

Comment: Ok but i just want to know the result of this condition. actually, i just see if all of your array is in otherArray, its because height are always > 24, maybe because div have always the same value

Comment: The height updates accurately in real time. Depending on the window's resizing, I have 24px, 48px, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how many items are in your array and if you are trying to do this for performance reasons...

Could you not use css to set a `max-height: 24px; overflow: hidden;` and then use React to toggle the max-height property?

Ie. https://codesandbox.io/s/red-wind-9c94z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: No, I need to display all the hidden items in a popover, that will appears after a click on the "show more" button. This is why I need two arrays. I can't simply switch between small & large divs.

Comment: What type of content is an item? Do you know the width of an item before hand or is the width relative?

Comment: An item is an object with 4 properties: id, color, label, and an array of objects called “data“. The latter have a number and a date.  I don’t know each item's width. It depends of its label length. The width is set by the parent component.

Comment: Try this: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-wind-9c94z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but it doesn't work as expected. When resizing the screen, the array is not updating. There are always 5 items to the top and the rest in the "show more" div. It's not updating in real time.

Comment: Resize events were not listed in your question as part of the requirements.You'll need to add resize event listeners for that functionality. It shouldn't be too hard to extend the functionality already there. On resize you should be able to just `setIsFull(false)` and the effect should re-calculate the items that fit.

Comment: This should now work as expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-wind-9c94z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Dane. Your exemple work, indeed. However, applying this script to mine doesn't do anything, I've checked multiple times if I made a typo, but apparently not. So I eventually came up with a crappy solution, which consists in dividing the available width by 10, which is approximately the width of a string character, and then cut the array once the script knows the next item won't fit in the line. Then, the remaining items are sent to another array dedicated to the button. It's ugly but it works. I'm ashamed by this script lol.